# Deleting Folder based on Name

Tags: linux, bash

I have a folder list with folders named 2014-01-0,2015-05-1 and so on where 01 and 05 is the number of the week considering 52 weeks in a year
I need to write a script in linux that keeps the latest 2 folders and deletes the rest. My solution is to store the list of directories in an array and then compare them but I cannot figure out on how to remove the "-" from the folder name and store it in an array. If you have any other solution feel free to mention it

Comment: `for name in ...; do name=${name//-/}; ...`?

Comment: Thanks a lot. New to scripting

Comment: @twalberg Can you help me on how to add it to array. I have just started scripting and the mentioned solution works but they aren't stored anywhere. What if I need to store the list as an array. I know that `array=($(ls -t */))` stores the list as an array but then I also need to remove the "-" from that array

Answer (score 0):

When all the weak-numbers beneuth 10 have a leading zero, you can just use the order given by ls.
Fetching the last two lines can be down with `tail -2`.
You want to skip these, the following solution is dirty (but nice for learning commands):

```
find . -type d -name 2\* | grep -v $(ls |tail -2|head -1) | grep -v $(ls | tail -1) | xargs echo rm -r
```

Removing the word echo will make things work, assuming you will have at least 2 directories. You should never assume...

When you first determine the dir's you want to keep (with tail/head) and store them in a var, you can exclude them after testing that they exist.